# using visual studio code python debugger step by step

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

When I launch `debug` -> `Start debugging` and then click on `step over`, `step into` or `continue` there is no action in the editor.

[image]

My launch config is:

[image]

What am I missing?